# Can't delete Music File

Tags: android, file, delete-file

I am trying to use the class `File` for deleting a file. For some reason it won't work. I debugged the program and found that `temp.exists()` is returning `true`. Where I am doing it wrong? BTW `temp.delete()` returns false ...

```
File temp = new File("/storage/extSdCard/Musik/A Careful Hope.mp3");

boolean exists = temp.exists();
boolean deleted = temp.delete();

if (deleted)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Successful deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem possibly is:

- The file exists, so `temp.exists()` returns **true**.
- But you don't have permissions over this file, so you can't delete it, and then `temp.delete()` returns **false**.

I suggest you to check if you have correctly declared:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

in you `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

If you have it correctly, check if the file or the directory are protected in some way, because I'm sure that the trouble you have is because for some reason you don't have the correct permissions to delete the file.

Comment: I checked it and Im not pretty sure Im using the permissions. The funny thing about it is that for example a MusicPlayer from a third party can delete this file but not me. What can it else be ?`Thanks for your help BTW is there any alternatives to class File ?

Comment: Just put the permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it should work. :)

Comment: Oh sry I misstyped , I mean im pretty sure ^^

Comment: Okay I don't know the reason then, but the problem is that for some reason you can't delete this file.

Comment: Yes. Theres also no way to find out what the error is right ? Its not throwing anything. I tried to catch it with (Exception e) .

Comment: We should investigate about it, maybe you can. I think it could be a good new question.